# Open multiple URLs in the Browser using NSWorkspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace

In my App I want to open multiple URLs in the web browser.

I do this like so:

```
int options = NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation | NSWorkspaceLaunchWithErrorPresentation;

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs: urls
                withAppBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.safari"
                                options: options
         additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil
                      launchIdentifiers: nil];
```

Safari now only ever opens six URLs at once and when I am using the `NSWorkspaceLaunchWithErrorPresentation` I get the following error message:

> You can’t open the application “Safari” because it is not responding.

[image: error-message]

Now when I set the bundle identifier to `com.google.Chrome` it is even worse and only 4 tabs are opened. Firefox (`org.mozilla.firefox`) opens 6 tabs as well.

Comment: How many urls do you want to open?

Comment: Well, more than six for sure. Maybe ten, maybe thirty. Some people I know have tons of tabs open all the time so I think six is very limiting.

Comment: True, maybe it's the all-at-once approach that is limiting it; try doing a `sleep(1);` after six iterations. `if (i == 6) sleep(1);` Just tried it and it works — even as hacky as it seems to be. Putting it in a dispatch queue was seemless - didn't even notice the `sleep(1)`

Comment: Okay, thanks for your research. I will look into this. If you post your approach as an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: I'd be glad to. I'll put a better example together too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to get around the limitation you've described would be to use a wait, or sleep function. It should allow you to open as many URLS as you decide:

```
-(void)openURLs {

for (int i = 0; i <= 18; i++) { // open 18 URLS for this example

        NSString *url = @"http://google.com";
        [self openURL:url];

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2f]; // wait .02 second
    }
}

- (void)openURL:(NSString *)url {

int options = NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation | NSWorkspaceLaunchWithErrorPresentation;

    NSArray *urls = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs: urls
                    withAppBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.safari"
                                    options: options
             additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil
                          launchIdentifiers: nil];
}
```

NOTE: Depending on how you want to load the urls (in the background, etc.) you could use a dispatch queue to load them using a separate thread.